# How to pass an user-varaible to he Router

Tags: laravel, forms, post, controller

I've a Laravel POST method like this

```
{!! Form::open([
  'action'  => 'SubvraagController@store',
  'method'  => 'POST',
  'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',])
!!}
```

Parameters (name, email etc) are set and this is working nicely.
But I also want to pass an user-variable (HeadID) to my controller.

I tried several ways, positions etc but it don't work. How can I pass HeadID to my SubvraagController?

This what I tried:

I want to pass my variable to SubvraagController. This is wat I tried:

```
{!! Form::open([
'action'  => 'SubvraagController@store',
'method'  => 'POST',
'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
'headid'=> $headID])
!!}
```

and this
Sorry but English is not my native language. Hopefully I can make it clearer.

I want to pass my variable to SubvraagController. This is wat I tried:

```
{!! Form::open([
'action'  => 'SubvraagController@store',
'method'  => 'POST',
'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
$headID])
!!}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please show us more of your code in the form, and in the controller.

Comment: Sorry but English is not my native language. Hopefully I can make it clearer.

I want to pass my variable to SubvraagController. This is wat I tried:
    {!! Form::open([
      'action'  => 'SubvraagController@store',
       'method'  => 'POST',
       'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
      'headid'=> $headID])
    !!}

Comment: what fields are being sent to the controller from the form? And by the way, no need for that form helper.

Comment: I've edit my questionand I hop this makes it clearer

Comment: Hereby the fields which are sent from the form:
{{Form::label('vraag', 'Subvraag')}}
                {{Form::text('vraag'   , '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Vul hier je vraag in'    ])}}
                {{Form::label('antwoord', 'Antwoord')}}
                {{Form::text('antwoord', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Vul hier het antwoord in'])}}
                {{Form::label('punten', 'Punten')}}
                {{Form::text('punten'  , '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Vul hier het aantal punten in '  ])}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like so:

Name your route. in your `web.php` file, name this route:
`Route::post('/yourEndPoint/{headID}', 'SubvraagController@store')->name('nameOfRoute');`

Next, you can do it like so:

```
<form action="route('nameOfRoute', $headID)" method="POST" 'enctype'='multipart/form-data'>
@csrf
 //rest of form
</form>
```

And in your controller:

```
public function store($headID){
//variable will be availble here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the current logged in user from anyway within Laravel using `Auth::user()`.

If HeadID is a user variable I would assume you would access it in your controller using:

`Auth::user()->head_id` if that is the right variable name you are using.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't use Auth and it's my mistake because the name User-variable